# Change location of marker using valid Zip code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I have the following requirement and trying to achieve this using jQUery:

1. Get the current location and show the markup in google map
2. Now change the location using valid Zip Code

I am able to show the current location but not sure how to change it using valid zip code, can anybody please suggest

Here is the code:

```js
var map, infoWindow;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 6
        });
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };

            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
            infoWindow.open(map);
            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
      }

      function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                              'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                              'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
      }
   
//Call this wherever needed to actually handle the display
function codeAddress(zipCode) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zipCode}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        //Got result, center the map and put it out there
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
  $("input").keyup(function(){
    alert("enter valid zip code");
  });
```

```css
.greybg {
 background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
.whitebg {
 background-color: #fff;
}
#map {
 height: 100%;
 min-height:400px;
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container whitebg">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">
         <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Zip Code">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCSnB7VUKtqjRqKC-3KA9nccHAX3PaMkIc&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. get current location and set marker

   ```
   <script>
     function initmap(){
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(currentLocation);
     }

     function currentLocation (position){
       var uluru = {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude};
       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
         zoom:10,
         center: uluru
       });
       marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: uluru,
         map:map
       })

     }

   </script>
   <script async defer
     src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD7g2FDEEEv1iAzha8xDJUvM1rN0yhaRgU&callback=initmap">
   </script>

   </script>
   ```

2.Now change the location using valid Zip Code

```
<p>Please enter your zip:</p>
<input id="zip" type="text" name="zip">
<input type="button" value="search" onclick="loadMapByZip()">
```

js

```
  var map, marker, geocoder;
  function loadMapByZip(){
    var lat = "";
    var lng= "";
    var zip = $("#zip").val();
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({'address':zip}, function(result, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        lat = result[0].geometry.location.lat();
        lng = result[0].geometry.location.lng();
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        map.panTo(center);
        marker.setPosition(center);
      } else {
        alert('invalid zip code');
      }
    });

  }
```

Comment: thanks very much for the answer, it worked perfectly as I was looking for